# HTML merge cells

Tags: html, css

as you can see my table has the cells all with individual borders.  I want them to be seamless vertial lines and horizaontal lineS...basically make the cell walls touch each other.  I asuume thats with the padding?

[image]

```
<table align="center" class="data_extract vert_scroll_table" >
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="heading" items="${results.headings}"> 
            <th class="data_extract">${heading}</th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${results.data}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}" varStatus="rowStatus">
                <td class="data_extract">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
                            <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                                ${elem}<c:if test="${!cellStatus.last}">,&nbsp;</c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            ${cell}
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.data_extract {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 2px gray solid;
}

td.data_extract,
th.data_extract,
table.data_extract td,
table.data_extract th {
    width: 125px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 7.5pt;
    white-space: normal;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: border-spacing: value; border-collapse:collapse;

Comment: Can you post an example like a jsfiddle? Your code doesn't match your image.

Comment: @j08691...sorry buddy...got to be quicker than that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a CSS style to the table called `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: Dang, a dollar short and a day late... : D

Comment: I gave you a little bump @PruitIgoe :)

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've styled tables but you might want to take a look at [border-collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp)

```
table { 
    border-collpase: collapse; 
}

table, td, th {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```